# How to trim down custom Skobbler offline map app size

Tags: ios, size, skmaps

I'm integrating Skobbler maps in my iOS app.

Right now, the app is 160Mb in size, which is way too much.
But I notice that there are bunch of maps integrated already. 
I would like to erase all maps and let the user download the ones he would need.

Right now, when I include SKMaps.framework, there is SKMaps document in it, that's 95Mb in size.

Is there any way to make this document smaller or downloadable after initial app is downloaded.

I have to make my app as small as possible. Also, as I don't need maps of the entire world, Is there a way do download some file with US maps only (even better option to download only the states a user would need)

Answer (score 4):

You could integrate only the desired packages. See how to deal with prebundled maps in this blog post:
http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-an-app-with-a-pre-bundled-map/

Also to minimize the size of the project you can do the following:

1. Remove all audio advices but en_us from SKAdvisorResources.bundle (Note: you can host & download the audio files on demand)
2. Remove Outdoorstyle and Grayscale style from SkMaps.bundle (if you're not using these styles)
3. Remove all other architectures but armv7 (there should be a small performance penalty on arm64, but since you exclude an entire set of architectures the size of the .ipa should be considerable smaller) - this change will be visible in the final .ipa file

Comment: Sylvia, thanks for your reply.

What you described works just fine, I just have another question.
There is a file SKMaps, inside the SKMaps.framework. That file is 95Mb and I cannot open it from any program. What should I do with that file?

Comment: Also, your OpenSourceDemo, with London map, like shown in the blog you linked, is 151Mb in size..that is still a very large app

Comment: Indeed there is work to do on reducing the app size, but it's on the list ("inside share")